# OLS or Ridge in Multicollinearity data

Tags: regression, least-squares, ridge-regression

I am new to stats and linear regression.  I just want to understand the exact scenario and usage between Ridge and OLS.  [Here is](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/sites/onlinecourses.science.psu.edu.stat501/files/data/bloodpress.txt) the data sample i have been using.

In this both Weight and BSA are highly correlated(in other words Multicollinearity).  I run the following two models,

LinearRegression:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/data/bloodpress.txt', index_col=0)
input = df.drop('BP',axis=1)
output = df.BP
llr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
llr.fit(input,output)
print(llr.coef_)
print(llr.predict([[56,95.7,2.09,7.0,75,99]]))
```

O/p

```
[ 0.70325939  0.96991978  3.776491    0.06838304 -0.08448469  0.0055715 ]
[ 121.92014732]
```

Ridge:

```
input = df.drop('BP',axis=1)
output = df.BP
llr = linear_model.Ridge()
llr.fit(input,output)
print(llr.coef_)
print(llr.predict([[56,95.7,2.09,7.0,75,99]]))
```

o/p

```
[ 0.71980652  1.08207683  0.276536    0.0640874  -0.12182558  0.00696796]
[ 121.87298902]
```

When we see the o/p OLS gives better solution.  The question is,

1) When i should go with Ridge?
2) In this example, Which will give better prediction ?